# Recursive loop over pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, recursion

**Input:**

```
| Company | Employee Number |
|---------|-----------------|
| 1       | 12              |
| 2       | 34, 12          |
| 3       | 56, 34, 78      |
| 4       | 90              |
```

**Goal:**

Find all employee numbers for an employee in all companies

**End Result:**

```
| Company | Employee Number |
|---------|-----------------|
| 1       | 12, 34, 56, 78  |
| 2       | 12, 34, 56, 78  |
| 3       | 12, 34, 56, 78  |
| 4       | 90              |
```

Notice from the result above that the first three lines are the same employee. We know that because the first employee number "12" exists in the second line, and the employee number "34" exists in rows 2 and 3. So, rows 1, 2 and 3 are all the same employee. So we concatenate the different employee numbers and display the result shown above.

Note: that you can have 0 or N number of Employee Numbers.

Is there a recursive way to do that? If not, what solution can you think of?

Comment: are you clear that, employee number is always undirected graph of 2 nodes ?

Comment: What is the dtype of `Employee Number` column, please?

Comment: @Nagakiran, employee number can have more than 2 values.
I will edit the issue accordingly to show that.

Comment: @Corralien, employee number is a string. So i guess the dtype will be object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would approach this (explanations in the comments):

```
# Replace NaN in df["Employee Number"] with empty string
df["Employee Number"] = df["Employee Number"].fillna("")

# Add a column with sets that contain the individual employee numbers
df["EN_Sets"] = df["Employee Number"].str.findall(r"\d+").apply(set)

# Build the maximal distinct employee number sets
en_sets = []
for en_set in df.EN_Sets:
    union_sets = []
    keep_sets = []
    for s in en_sets:
        if s.isdisjoint(en_set):
            keep_sets.append(s)
        else:
            union_sets.append(s)
    en_sets = keep_sets + [en_set.union(*union_sets)]

# Build a dictionary with the replacement strings as keys the distinct sets
# as values
en_sets = {", ".join(sorted(s)): s for s in en_sets}

# Apply-function to replace the original employee number strings
def setting_en_numbers(s):
    for en_set_str, en_set in en_sets.items():
        if not s.isdisjoint(en_set):
            return en_set_str

# Apply the function to df["Employee Number"]
df["Employee Number"] = df.EN_Sets.apply(setting_en_numbers)
df = df[["Company", "Employee Number"]]
```

Result for

```
df:
   Company Employee Number
0        1              12
1        2          34, 12
2        3      56, 34, 78
3        4              90
4        5             NaN
```

is

```
   Company Employee Number
0        1  12, 34, 56, 78
1        2  12, 34, 56, 78
2        3  12, 34, 56, 78
3        4              90
4        5
```